# How can I use MySQL alias in Where condition

Tags: mysql, notifications, alert, alias

I have column with only date of the months in a table,
table_date
17
13
12
04
Now I would like to check where these date are lesser than current date
This is what I am trying, or is there any other better way.

`select concat(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m'),'-',table_date) as duedate from dhr where due date < curdate()`
I have error as
`Unknown column 'duedate' in 'where clause'`

Comment: What code do you have so far? What have you actually tried if anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found concatenating must be done in where condition

`select table_date from table_name where concat(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y-%m'),'-',table_date) < curdate()`